# auth::attempt($credentials) not work in other controller in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a custom need where I am trying to connect Laravel with Django app. Currently, I am not using laravel's default login post method to establish user session, instead of that I am trying to access Auth::attempt($credentials);. By this way, I am able to establish user session in my custom login controller whereas in other controllers the session is not established.

**Login controller:**

```
 $credentials = array('email' => $userjson["email"],'password' => $password);
    Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if(Auth::guest())
     echo "guest";
    else
     return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
```

**Result:** redirect to the dashboard page (which means session is established)

**Dashboard controller**

```
     if(Auth::check())
              echo "true";
            else
                echo "false";
```

**Result:** false (which means the session is not established)

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: In your $username are you sending password?

Comment: srry... $username is my local variable contain password

Comment: Use `dd` to review the variables ensure they're correct?  What is `$userjson`?  Also, using `dd(\Hash::make($password))` can you test your query to make sure you get the records you expect?

Comment: this is my dd(Auth::user()) result :

Comment: this is my dd(Auth::user()) give my expected results. but in guard it give following result #guarded: array:1 [▼0 => "*" ] it's correct. i have properly implemented the hash::make function store the credentials in my user table and i am passing raw password variable to attempt method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .we'll need to make sure to import the Auth facade at the top of the class .For more help go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication and ready topic Manually Authenticating Users. Thanks

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;

class OtherController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```